# How to use one to calculate next row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id':[1,1,1,2,2],
        'prod_type':['A','B','C','A','C'],
        'prod_order':[1,3,2,2,1],
        'prod_price':[100,150,300,10,40]
        'prod_pool':[200,200,200,45,45]
       }
```

For each group identified by id, I need to order the products by prod order and cap the price with the available pool, row by row, but the product pool is consumed at each step.

So the first row I'll get id=1, prod_type=A, prod_used=min(prod_price,prod_pool)

Then the second row id=1, prod_type=C, prod_used=min(prod_price,max(0,prod_pool(productA)-prod_used(productA)))

So basically every time a product "uses" part of the pool, the pool is reduced by that amount.
The pool cannot be negative, so once is used up there is nothing left and must be 0.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with a custom function:

```
# read data and sort by prod_order
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by=['id', 'prod_order'])

def quantity(g):
    # compute the shifted difference
    s = g['prod_pool'].sub(g['prod_price'].shift()).fillna(g['prod_price'])
    # stop at the first negative value
    return s.where(s.gt(0).cummin(), 0)

df['product_used'] = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(quantity)
```

Output:

```
   id prod_type  prod_order  prod_price  prod_pool  product_used
0   1         A           1         100        200         100.0
2   1         C           2         300        200         100.0
1   1         B           3         150        200           0.0
4   2         C           1          40         45          40.0
3   2         A           2          10         45           5.0
```